# Count value issue in HTML Table using PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, count

I would like to show the count value for the mysql result in html table.

For an example "district Name1" is the name of "district name" and "count-value1" shows the total post office count in "district name1".

My output must be like this,

```
------------------------
District | Post Offices
------------------------
Name1    | Count-Value1
Name2    | Count-Value2
Name3    | Count-Value3
Name4    | Count-Value4
...      | ...
------------------------
```

Anyone can please help me to fix this..

This is my PHP code,

```
<?php
    include('config.php');  
    $data_content= "";
    $qry = "SELECT DISTINCT district_N,state_N FROM pincode_data WHERE state_N ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['st'])."' ORDER BY district_N ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $dist_Value = $row['district_N'];
            $state_Value = $row['state_N'];
            $data_content.= "<tr><td><a href='pincity.php?dist=".$row['district_N']."'> ".$row['district_N']."</a></td><td>Count Value to be Displayed Here</td></tr>";
        }
    mysql_close();
?>
```

This is my HTML code,

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Pincodes in <?php echo $state_Value; ?></h1>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr><td>District</td><td>Post Offices</td></tr>
            <?php echo $data_content; ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: generally, to get a count of X in sql, you `group by` x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL has syntax for counting elements of a group.  If you want to count all occurrences of each value for X in a table, the general form is `select X, count(X) from <table> GROUP BY X`.  This will group all equal values of X together, and give you a total count of them.  For your particular case, try this:

```
$qry = "SELECT district_N,state_N, COUNT(district_N) cnt 
  FROM pincode_data WHERE state_N ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['st'])."'
  GROUP BY district_N ORDER BY district_N ASC";
```

Also, it is good to see that you are escaping the parameters - but `mysql_*` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP. You are best off to use either `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.  In either case, you should also look into prepared statements and parameter binding. It's good for your health.